# Search view inside spinner dialog

Tags: android

i have spinner and i want to add Search View inside spinner but how can i done it.
My app shows search view above spinner like this [My App shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr1aF.png)

But instead i want it to be inside spinner when user click spinner it shows Search View and list of items like this 
[After clicking spinner it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Z3H.png)

myFragment.xml

```
 <SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sCity"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/city"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a library which has the exact same functionality you are looking for. The library is called [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) which is the same as a normal android spinner but on tapping the spinner, it would open a dialog with searchview and the list of items set in the adapter.

[GIF for the view](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/res/nobleltevzwLMY47XMeditab02192016201518.gif) Please click on the link to view the gif related to the library.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially What kind of behavior is expected of users?'s last section: [Avoid overt self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/how-can-i-advertise-on-stack-overflow)